# Is this HNQ question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question

[This question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/49288/23927) was posted yesterday, asking how two characters on non-overlapping shifts could plausibly form a rapport with one another. This appears to me to be a textbook "what to write" question - the OP is asking for help writing their storyline - and therefore off-topic. I voted to close for that reason.

As of the time of my first revision, only one other person has voted to close, and the question has hit HNQ. My fear is that people will come here from HNQ, assume that story-writing questions are on-topic here, and ask more of them, exacerbating the [issues we already have](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2282/23927) with low-quality questions.

What gives me pause for thought is that, of the six answers so far, one of them is by the highest-rep user on the entire site. I would have expected him to VTC if the question really was off-topic. So it's possible I'm being overzealous.

So: **Is this question on-topic after all?** If so, then how come it doesn't count as "what to write"? If not, then considering our lack of moderators and active power users, how can we get it taken off HNQ and closed?

Comment: I don't suggest closing the question. If it's decided that it really doesn't belong here, maybe migrate it to WorldBuilding SE.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza They'd *definitely* close it as off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I am, admittedly, new here, but as far as I can tell, this question passes muster because it manages to frame the question as a generic situation to which answers can potentially provide value to more people than just the OP (see the answer [here](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/138)).

Comment: I'm still not convinced, but after reading the linked Meta question, I can see your point. I may have to take a look at the question's answers; if most of them are general instead of catering specifically to the OP, that would be a good sign.